# React-rte Rich Text Editor change button colors

Tags: css, reactjs, rich-text-editor, rte

I am trouble changing the background color of the toolbar buttons. Please refer to the image link. Currently the buttons are in light grey of color.

**Image Link**

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEEWt.png)

**My Code**

```
 <div className="input-field">
                            <label id="together" className="borderline">Create Post</label>
                            <RichTextEditor
                                className="text-editor"
                                editorClassName="class-editor"
                                toolbarClassName= "tool-editor"
                                
                                toolbarConfig={toolbarConfig}
                                value={this.state.content}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>
```

**My CSS**

```
.text-editor:focus-within{ 

  box-shadow: 0 0px 0 0 orange !important;
  border: 2px solid orange !important;


}


div.input-field:focus-within .tool-editor{

  color: orange !important;
}
```

**What I have done**

I've played with the css for the className,editorClassName & toolbarClassName. But none of them seems to change the background color of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying styles to this class

```
.MuiIconButton-root
```

It will apply your styles on the buttons of the editor